# Only one and first div is triggered when click

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, dom-events

I wanted to log the elements of the clicked button to the console, but it only worked for "CLICK ME 1." It did not work for another button.

```js
var testLog = (function(){

    var getButton = document.querySelector('.button__');
    getButton.addEventListener('click', checkPlease);

    function checkPlease(event){
        console.log(event.target);
    }

})();
```

```html
<section class="product">
<div class="product__wrapper">
    <div class="item">
       <button class="button__">CLICK ME 1</button>
       <button class="button__">CLICK ME 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `querySelectorAll` to get all the elements and then `forEach` on the returned nodelist to attach `addEventListener` to each element

```
var getButtonList = document.querySelectorAll('.button__');
getButtonList.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', checkPlease));
```

Answer (score 1):

you get only first button, because of `document.querySelector` in your code. Use `document.querySelectorAll` instead

Attach your event listener to all elements, using loop, like this:

```
var getButton = document.querySelectorAll('.button__');

getButton.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', checkPlease))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: you need to use querySelectorAll:

```
var getButton = document.querySelectorAll(".button__");
if (getButton && getButton.length > 0) {
    getButton.forEach((element) => {
        element.addEventListener("click", checkPlease);
    });
}

function checkPlease(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a listener per button, you can use event delegation by adding a single listener to the parent element and differentiating by target details.

```js
const testLog = (function(){

    const buttonContainer = document.querySelector('.item');
    buttonContainer.addEventListener('click', checkPlease);

    function checkPlease(event){
        console.log(event.target);
    }

})();
```

```html
<section class="product">
<div class="product__wrapper">
    <div class="item">
       <button class="button__">CLICK ME 1</button>
       <button class="button__">CLICK ME 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```